# Buildfire:Barcode Scanning Service working in Previewer app, but not in built app on android

Tags: buildfire

I am developing a Buildfire plugin that requires QR Code scanning.
I have used the code below and it works in the previewer app,
but fails to scan on the built app that is on the play store (only tested on Android).

```
function scan(){
    buildfire.services.camera.barcodeScanner.scan(
        {
            preferFrontCamera : false,
            showFlipCameraButton : true,
            formats : "QR_CODE", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
        },
        function (err, result) {
            buildfire.notifications.alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            rcpt = result.text;
            console.log(rcpt);
            document.getElementById("recipient").value = rcpt;
        }
    );
}
```

Launch function with button.
Works in previewer.
Fails in built (android) app

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you request the `BarCodeScanner` feature in your `plugin.json` see the Prerequisite portion of the API Doc https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Barcode-Scanning-Service

Note: Your app will require a hard build.

I hope this helps

Comment: We added: "features" : [{"name" : "GPS"} ,{"name" : "BarCodeScanner"}] to the plugin.json file, But it did not open the BarCodeScanner. Can you suggest a way to debug this issue?

Comment: I just noticed that the app on the Google Play store doesn't list camera under Permission / View details , could this be preventing the bar Code scanner from working?

Comment: In the developer portal, there are debugging tools to debug on a live app. One of the tools is Weiner that will allow you to debug remotely. As for Camera service, you definitely need it. Are you sure you android and ios app got rebuilt? if not contact customer support and they should be able to help.